# centos 7 with adaptex and problem with snmp

Tags: centos, raid, snmp

I have a supermicor server with centos 7 and adaptec 6504e and i monitor all of my servers hard disks by snmp with observium, i followed the adaptec user manual for enable snmp sub agent but observium can not detect status of my adaptec raid by snmp.
when i run ./aup-snmpd in storman i have following erros :
Cannot find module (IF-MIB): At line 0 in (none)

Cannot find module (TCP-MIB): At line 0 in (none)

Cannot find module (UDP-MIB): At line 0 in (none)

Cannot find module (HOST-RESOURCES-MIB): At line 0 in (none)

Cannot find module (SNMPv2-MIB): At line 0 in (none)

Cannot find module (SNMPv2-SMI): At line 0 in (none)

Cannot find module (NOTIFICATION-LOG-MIB): At line 0 in (none)

Cannot find module (DISMAN-EVENT-MIB): At line 0 in (none)

Cannot find module (DISMAN-SCHEDULE-MIB): At line 0 in (none)

Cannot find module (UCD-SNMP-MIB): At line 0 in (none)

Cannot find module (UCD-DEMO-MIB): At line 0 in (none)

Cannot find module (SNMP-TARGET-MIB): At line 0 in (none)

Cannot find module (NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB): At line 0 in (none)

Cannot find module (HOST-RESOURCES-TYPES): At line 0 in (none)

Cannot find module (SNMP-VIEW-BASED-ACM-MIB): At line 0 in (none)

Cannot find module (SNMP-COMMUNITY-MIB): At line 0 in (none)

Cannot find module (IP-FORWARD-MIB): At line 0 in (none)

Cannot find module (NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB): At line 0 in (none)

Cannot find module (UCD-DLMOD-MIB): At line 0 in (none)

Cannot find module (SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB): At line 0 in (none)

Cannot find module (SNMP-MPD-MIB): At line 0 in (none)

Cannot find module (SNMP-USER-BASED-SM-MIB): At line 0 in (none)

Cannot find module (SNMP-NOTIFICATION-MIB): At line 0 in (none)

Cannot find module (SNMPv2-TM): At line 0 in (none)

NET-SNMP version 5.3.1 AgentX subagent connected

any idea how to solve this?
Thanks,